# How to download file in my SD card folder in Android

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I want download file from server and for this work i use this **library** : https://github.com/ayz4sci/DownloadProgress , and write below codes :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DownloadProgressView.DownloadStatusListener {

    private Button downloadButton, playButton;
    private long downloadID;
    private String downloadURL = "http://cld8.cdn.p30download.com/p30dl-mobile/AppMgr.Pro.III.v4.00.Patched_p30download.com.apk";
    private DownloadManager downloadManager;
    private DownloadProgressView downloadProgressView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);

        final File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "dirName");

        if(!myDirectory.exists()) {
            myDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        downloadProgressView = (DownloadProgressView) findViewById(R.id.downloadProgressView);
        downloadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downloadButton);
        downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downloadURL));
                request.setTitle("You garrit");
                request.setDescription("DownloadProgress sample");
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(), "myCustomFolderName", "p30download.com.apk");
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

                downloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                downloadProgressView.show(downloadID, new DownloadProgressView.DownloadStatusListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void downloadFailed(int reason) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void downloadSuccessful() {

                        playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(getFileUri()), "apk/*");
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void downloadCancelled() {
                        downloadButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
                downloadButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public File getFileUri() {
        DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
        query.setFilterById(downloadID);
        Cursor cur = downloadManager.query(query);

        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
            if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == cur.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                String uriString = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                return new File(Uri.parse(uriString).getPath());
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void downloadFailed(int reason) {
        System.err.println("Failed :" + reason);
        downloadButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void downloadSuccessful() {
        playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void downloadCancelled() {
        downloadButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

I want when download successful, save this file into my folder. for this work i use this code :

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(), "myCustomFolderName", "p30download.com.apk");
```

but when download finished i can't show **myCustomFolder** name in SD card, and i don't know where save my downloaded file!

How can i fix this issue? Please help me, thanks all <3

Comment: If I am getting you correctly you want to save file in myCustomFolder  folder in sd card but you are not able to see that folder in sd card

Comment: @jiteshmohite, how can i fix this? please help me my dear friend

Comment: ok do you have sd card right in your device

Comment: @jiteshmohite, yes my friend. i can create folder in sd card with this code : `final File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "dirName");
        if(!myDirectory.exists()) {
            myDirectory.mkdirs();
        }`  but i should create folder and save that with this code : `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(), "myCustomFolderName", "p30download.com.apk");`  in this library! when use this code not create folder and not save file in this folder!

Comment: @jiteshmohite, are you here? can you help me?

Comment: give me minutes i am trying

Comment: @jiteshmohite, Thank you my friend, thanks <3 . i will wating

Comment: please try I have answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code inside onCLick of download

```
  File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/myCustomFolderName");
                dir.mkdirs();
                File file = new File(dir, "you_garrit.mp4");
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downloadURL));
                request.setTitle("You garrit");
                request.setDescription("DownloadProgress sample");
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationUri(uri);
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

                downloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                downloadProgressView.show(downloadID, new DownloadProgressView.DownloadStatusListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void downloadFailed(int reason) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "downloadFailed" + reason);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void downloadSuccessful() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "downloadSuccessful");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void downloadCancelled() {
                      Log.d(TAG, "downloadCancelled");
                    }
                });
                downloadButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

please let me know if these dosen't work for you

Comment: WoWWWWWWWW!!!! you are awesome, thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks my dear friend. thanks thankssssss <3

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the download, try to create the folder using `mkdirs`.

```
File file = new File(String path)
file.mkDirs();
```

`mkDirs()` is as boolean so you can check wether it's creating the folder correctly or not.

Comment: can you send me full code with my above codes? please

Answer (score 0):

Use [ion android](https://github.com/koush/ion) library very simple and easy to use

Sample code to download file is

```
Ion.with(context)
.load("http://example.com/really-big-file.zip")
// have a ProgressBar get updated automatically with the percent
.progressBar(progressBar)
// and a ProgressDialog
.progressDialog(progressDialog)
// can also use a custom callback
.progress(new ProgressCallback() {@Override
   public void onProgress(long downloaded, long total) {
       System.out.println("" + downloaded + " / " + total);
   }
})
.write(new File("/sdcard/really-big-file.zip"))
.setCallback(new FutureCallback<File>() {
   @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception e, File file) {
        // download done...
        // do stuff with the File or error
    }
});
```

Don't forget to add required permissions. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I trying ION. but in ion not show download in Notification and not downlaod in service!

Comment: Use this library to create notification https://github.com/halysongoncalves/Pugnotification